# AKS using Terraform - Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.70.0: unexpected EOF

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terragrunt

I'm using Ubuntu LTS 20.04. Trying to build AKS cluster with Terrfaorm(v0.15.4). Terragrunt(v0.31.1) runs on top of it. After creating a resource group in Azure, while trying to import it, it gives me error. Any idea or any guidance on how to debug this error would also do a help.

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.15.4
on linux_amd64

$ echo $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_ID
/subscriptions/23431111-2222-111-8910-2ee44a5161we/resourceGroups/my-rg

$ terragrunt import azurerm_resource_group.k8s "$AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_ID"

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 2.55"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.70.0...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.70.0: unexpected EOF
╵

ERRO[0030] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you try to generate new client-secret(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) and rerun terragrunt?

Comment: @AndriyBilous, No I have not tried anything like that. Do you suspect it's the cause or solution?

Comment: Please try to generate new client-secret(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) and let me know if issue is resolved

Comment: @AndriyBilous, Tried to do it. But it didn't change anything. Still receiving the same "unexpected EOF" error.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the cause. It was the corporate proxy which prevents me to download the zip files from https://releases.hashicorp.com/